# При обновлении страницы ошибка 404

Tags: javascript, html, маршрутизация, href, history-api

Код на Vanills js, SPA

При обновлении любой страницы, кроме главной, вылетает ошибка 404.

Роутер:

```js
"use strict";

const routes = {
  "/": "./pages/activity.html",
  "/home": "./pages/activity.html",
  "/map": "./pages/map.html",
  "/time": "./pages/time.html",
};

const route = (event) => {
  event = event || window.event;
  event.preventDefault();
  window.history.pushState({}, "", event.target.href);
  handleLocation();
};

const handleLocation = async () => {
  const parsePath = window.location.pathname.split("/");
  const path = "/" + parsePath[parsePath.length - 1];
  const html = await fetch(routes[path]).then((data) => data.text());
  document.getElementById("app").innerHTML = html;

  updateActiveButtons(path);
};

// Отслеживает back, go
window.addEventListener("popstate", handleLocation);

// Для начальной обработки
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", handleLocation);
```

Кнопка для перехода на страницу:

```html
<a href="map">
  <p>Map</p>
</a>
```

Comment: 404 - значит физически такой страницы нет. Тебе нужно чтобы твой сервер, на такого типа запросы, тебе возвращал твою "главную" страницу, которая так же будет подгружать нужное, которое зависит от указанного УРЛ.

Comment: хм, спасибо. не подскажешь, как на чистом js отловить 404 и перенаправить? и можешь ли сказать, почему физически страницы нет, ведь я перезагружаю существующую?

Comment: отловить думаю можно через фетч->кетч

Comment: Вот смотри, ты открыл `index.html` (она есть) УРЛ `http://test`, поменял УРЛ `http://test/info`, сделал перехват этого. Подгрузил что нужно. Потом обновляешь и это уже не `index.html`, идет запрос на другой УРЛ и именно этой `http://test/info` страницы нет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если кто-то тоже столкнулся с такой проблемой на github pages, то отловить такую ошибку можно создав в корне проекта файл 404.html, теперь дефолтная страница заменится на кастомную, в которой можно уже хендлер прописать